# C# charts to fit in one tab

Tags: c#, wpf

I have C# code that makes tabs.I have to combine 4 tabs into 1. at the bottom left here you can see:

[image: Screenshot]

Code for this: I think the issue is pinpointed to the grid row and grid column, as you can see there is overlap and the 4rth tab is not showing at all.

```
        <Button x:Class="TDashboard.Common.Modules.CNASummary.Views.CNASummaryTileView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=WPFVisifire.Charts"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="280"
    d:DesignWidth="560"
    MinHeight="{StaticResource TileMinHeight}"
    MinWidth="{StaticResource TileMinWidth}"
    MaxHeight="{StaticResource TileMaxHeight}"
    MaxWidth="{StaticResource TileMaxWidth}"
    Command="{Binding Command}"
    Template="{StaticResource TileControlTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
            dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="260" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="260" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <vc:Chart x:Name="CNAPoorEating"
              Watermark="False"
              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              MinHeight="60"
              MinWidth="{StaticResource ChartMinWidth}"
              CornerRadius="11,11,11,11"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              FontSize="8"
              Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <vc:Chart.PlotArea>
                <vc:PlotArea Background="#00000000" />
            </vc:Chart.PlotArea>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title Text="Num. Patients Poor Eating" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis IntervalType="Days"
                     ValueFormatString="MMM-d"
                     Interval="1">
                    <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                        <vc:AxisLabels Angle="0" />
                    </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                </vc:Axis>
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>
            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Column"
                           DataSource="{Binding CNAPoorEatingData}"
                           XValueFormatString="MMM-d">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="XValue"
                                    Path="Day" />
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="YValue"
                                    Path="Count" />
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>

        <vc:Chart x:Name="CNABathing"
              Watermark="False"
              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              MinHeight="60"
              MinWidth="{StaticResource ChartMinWidth}"
              CornerRadius="11,11,11,11"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              FontSize="8"
              Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <vc:Chart.PlotArea>
                <vc:PlotArea Background="#00000000" />
            </vc:Chart.PlotArea>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title Text="CNABathing" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis IntervalType="Days"
                     ValueFormatString="MMM-d"
                     Interval="1">
                    <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                        <vc:AxisLabels Angle="0" />
                    </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                </vc:Axis>
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>
            <vc:Chart.Series>


                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Column"
                           DataSource="{Binding CNABathingData}"
                           XValueFormatString="MMM-d">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="XValue"
                                    Path="Day" />
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="YValue"
                                    Path="Count" />
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>

        <vc:Chart x:Name="CNABowel"
              Watermark="False"
              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              MinHeight="60"
              MinWidth="{StaticResource ChartMinWidth}"
              CornerRadius="11,11,11,11"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              FontSize="8"
              Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
            <vc:Chart.PlotArea>
                <vc:PlotArea Background="#00000000" />
            </vc:Chart.PlotArea>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title Text="CNABowel" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis IntervalType="Days"
                     ValueFormatString="MMM-d"
                     Interval="1">
                    <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                        <vc:AxisLabels Angle="0" />
                    </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                </vc:Axis>
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>
            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Column"
                           DataSource="{Binding CNASource}"
                              XValueFormatString="MMM-d">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="XValue"
                                    Path="Day" />
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="YValue"
                                    Path="Count" />
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>

        <vc:Chart x:Name="CNAIntakeVsOutput"
              Watermark="False"
              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              MinHeight="60"
              MinWidth="{StaticResource ChartMinWidth}"
              CornerRadius="11,11,11,11"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              FontSize="8"
              Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
            <vc:Chart.PlotArea>
                <vc:PlotArea Background="#00000000" />
            </vc:Chart.PlotArea>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title Text="CNAIntakeVsOutput" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.AxesX>
                <vc:Axis IntervalType="Days"
                     ValueFormatString="MMM-d"
                     Interval="1">
                    <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                        <vc:AxisLabels Angle="0" />
                    </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
                </vc:Axis>
            </vc:Chart.AxesX>
            <vc:Chart.Series>
                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Column"
                           DataSource="{Binding Data}"
                           XValueFormatString="MMM-d">
                    <vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="XValue"
                                    Path="Day" />
                        <vc:DataMapping MemberName="YValue"
                                    Path="Count" />
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>



                            </Grid>

                      </StackPanel>
               </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid Row and Column indexes start at 0. Since your grid is 2x2, the highest Column/Row index available is 1, but you have it set to 2 on `CNAIntakeVsOutput` and `CNABowel`

Since the specified Row/Column doesn't exist, the default position is 0, which means you have two objects on top of each other (take a closer look at the 2nd column in the 1st row)

Change your Grid.Row and Grid.Column on `CNAIntakeVsOutput` and `Grid.Column` on `CNABowel` to 1 and it should render correctly.

**Edit**

I would also recommend using * size columns in your Grid, instead of aboslute ones, so they the entire object shows regardless of screen size.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

This will make your Grid have two equally-size columns and two equally sized rows.

Comment: Thank you very much Rachel. I made them 0 0, 0 1, 1 0, and 1 1.

Comment: The only issue is the bottom charts get cut off a bit:  http://www.mediafire.com/?e5zmfjbpujbfjze

Comment: @user527397 See the update to my answer. You are setting absolute sizes, which make the content exceed the available width. Either use `*` sizes, or add a `ScrollViewer`